# Looping for pg_fetch_row

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

how if I need is looping in php to insert the data for up to 6 rows. Because if I use this code it just only appear once insertion and not repeated.

```
while ($row=pg_fetch_row($sql1))
{
$sqlinsert="insert into rpt_printing_detail values (  '$row[0]','$row[1]','$row[2]','$row[3]','$row[4]','$row[5]','$row[6]','$row[7]','$row[8]','$row[9]')";
}
```

For data like this
[image]

My code just insert one insertion :

```
insert into rpt_printing_detail values ( '201501', 'Detail Billing', '1', '1', '16397', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' )
```

Comment: Did you try to run your query `$sql1`? Is your query returning multiple rows or just one row? Can you please show the result of `$sql`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code creates a SQL query as a string. It doesn't do anything to the database.

Presumably a later statement outside the loop runs the query in the variable, like:

```
while ($row=pg_fetch_row($sql1))
{
$sqlinsert="insert into rpt_printing_detail values (  '$row[0]','$row[1]','$row[2]','$row[3]','$row[4]','$row[5]','$row[6]','$row[7]','$row[8]','$row[9]')";
}
pg_query($sqlinsert);
```

Since there's only one query - you overwrite it with each loop - it only makes one change.

Irrespective of the issue here, you have a major bug. Read [the PHP documentation on SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) then use `pg_query_params` or preferably PDO.